# MySQL Help: Return invoices and payments by date

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting a MySQL query to work for me. Here is the setup.

A customer has asked me to compile a report from some accounting data. He wants to select a date (and possibly other criteria) and have it return all of the following (an OR statement):
1.) All invoices that were inserted on or after that date
2.) All invoices regardless of their insert date that have corresponding payments in a separate table whose insert dates are on or after the selected date.

The first clause is basic, but I am having trouble pairing it with the second.

I have assembled a comparable set of test data in an SQL Fiddle. The query that I currently have is provided.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8d9c/3/2

As noted in the comments of the fiddle, I am working with July 1, 2013 as my selected date. For the test to work, I need invoices 1 through 5 to appear, but not invoice #6.

Comment: here's a kick in the right direction: the solution is going to involve joining the invoice and payments tables.  as there might not be payments yet you'll need to use the LEFT OUTER JOIN type.  start with something like: LEFT OUTER JOIN test_payments tp ON tp.invoiceid = i.iid.  then you'll probably need to GROUP BY tp.invoiceid and calculate the MAX(tp.dataddded) AS max_added and add a WHERE max_added > @startdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8d9c/9
Here are the summarized changes

1. I got rid of your `GROUP BY`.   You did not have any aggregate functions.  I used `DISTINCT` instead to eliminate duplicate records
2. I removed your implicit joins and put explicit joins in their place for readability.  Then I changed them to LEFT JOINs.  I am not sure what your data looks like but at a minimum, I would assume you need the payments LEFT JOINed if you want to select an invoice that has no payments.
3. This will probably get you the records you want, but those subselects in the `SELECT` clause may perform better as LEFT JOINs then using the SUM function

Here is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.abbr landowner,
    CONCAT(f.ForestLabel, '-', l.serial, '-', l.revision) leasenumber,
    i.iid,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(i.dateadded,'%M %d, %Y') InvoiceDate,
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ch.amount), 0.00) n FROM test_charges ch WHERE ch.invoiceid = i.iid) totalBilled,
    (SELECT SUM(p1.amount) n FROM test_payments p1 WHERE p1.invoiceid = i.iid AND p1.transtype = 'check' AND p1.status = 2) checks,
    (SELECT SUM(p1.amount) n FROM test_payments p1 WHERE p1.invoiceid = i.iid AND p1.transtype = 'ach' AND p1.status = 2) ach,
    CASE WHEN i.totalbilled < 0 THEN i.totalbilled * -1 ELSE 0.00 END credits,
    CASE WHEN i.balance >= 0 THEN i.balance ELSE 0.00 END balance,
    t.typelabel, g.groupname
FROM test_invoices i
LEFT JOIN test_contracts c
  ON     i.contractid = c.cid 
LEFT JOIN test_leases l
  ON c.leaseid = l.bid
LEFT JOIN test_forest f
  ON l.forest = f.ForestID
LEFT JOIN test_leasetypes t
  ON l.leasetype = t.tid
LEFT JOIN test_accounts a
  ON l.account = a.aid
LEFT JOIN test_groups g
  ON c.groupid = g.gid
LEFT JOIN test_payments p
  ON p.invoiceid = i.iid
WHERE (i.dateadded >= @startdate) OR (p.dateadded >= @startdate)
```

Comment: At first glance, I think you nailed it. I am running this through my production data and see if it gives me the proper result. I will be back to accept your answer if all looks good. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8d9c/11/2

TL;DR:

```
… AND (i.dateadded > @startdate
     OR EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM test_payments
       WHERE test_payments.invoiceid = i.iid
       AND  test_payments.dateadded >= @startdate))
```